# MVC: model of type Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that inherits from `ViewUserControl<Guid?>` - i.e. it's model is of type `Nullable<Guid>`. Very simple view, nothing special, but that's not the point.

Somewhere else, I do `Html.RenderPartial( "MyView", someGuid )`, where `someGuid` is of type `Nullable<Guid>`. Everything's perfectly legal, should work OK, right?

But here's the gotcha: the second argument of `Html.RenderPartial` is of type `object`, and therefore, `Nullable<Guid>` being a value type, it must be boxed. But nullable types are somehow *special* in the CLR, so that when you box one of those, you actually get either a boxed value of type `T` (Nullable's argument), or a null if the nullable didn't have a value to begin with. And that last case is actually interesting.

Turns out, sometimes, I do have a situation when `someGuid.HasValue == false`. And in those cases, I effectively get a call `Html.RenderPartial( "MyView", null )`. And what does the HtmlHelper do when the model is null? Believe it or not, it just goes ahead and takes the parent view's model. Regardless of it's type.

So, naturally, in those cases, I get an exception saying: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Parent.View.Model.Type', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Guid?'"

So the question is: **how do I make MVC correctly pass `new Nullable<Guid> { HasValue = false }` instead of trying to grab the parent's model?**

**Note**: I did consider wrapping my `Guid?` in an object of another type, specifically created for this occasion, but this seems completely ridiculous. Don't want to do that as long as there's another way.

**Note 2**: now that I've wrote all this, I've realized that the question may be reduced to *how to pass a null for model without ending up with parent's model?*

Comment: It almost seems like using a default guid might be in order...something that represents "no guid." like `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

Comment: Well, I did consider that as well for a moment... And it seems almost as ridiculous. And besides, what if I actually need to distinguish between null and zero?

Comment: Are you passing the entire model to the partial, a subset of the model, or just a GUID? Because it seems to me that if you are just passing the GUID, and looking up information from the database to display using the GUID, then your partial "knows too much," and `RenderAction` would be more appropriate.

Comment: No, it doesn't look up anything. In full accordance with best practices and other goodness, it only uses the GUID, nothing else. It just displays a bunch of HTML tags where the GUID in question is embedded in some of attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("MyView", someGuid ?? new Guid()); %>
```

---

UPDATE:

Using editor and/or display templates in ASP.NET MVC 2.0 you can achieve the desired result. Place a `Guid.ascx` file in the `Shared/EditorTemplates` folder and include it like this:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => someGuid) %>
```

or if the guid is a property of the main model:

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeGuid) %>
```

Now if you put a `<%= Model.HasValue %>` inside the partial you can get `false` but not with `RenderPartial`.

Comment: But that will give me an empty GUID instead of null, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it will. Using `RenderPartial` you cannot achieve this effect.

Comment: Regarding your update: I don't see any HtmlHelper's extension methods with an "Editor" word in them which would take a lambda. Did you make a typo of some sort? (and yes, I'm using MVC 2.0; have VS2010 installed)

Comment: Oh, there is such a method. See this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/11/27/extending-asp-net-mvc-2-templates.aspx Try creating a new ASP.NET MVC 2.0 project and there you will find the EditorFor method.

Comment: That article only mentions `EditorForModel` method, which I do see. But it doesn't take lambda or delegate. And I have created my project only a couple of days ago, and it's almost virgin at this point.

Comment: I have no idea why you are not seeing this method but it definitely exists. Maybe a bug in the Intellisense? Here's another article: http://lsd.luminis.nl/asp-net-mvc-editor-templates/ And on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834942(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Ok, I found it finally. It extends templated `HtmlHelper<T>`, while I was trying to call it on non-templated `HtmlHelper`. And it works now. Thanks!